# Follow-up email after faculty position interview

Tags: job-search, recruiting

I followed up and was told that "we are still navigating the university's recruitment process, so still need several weeks to provide update". Could anyone explain what does it mean? Does it imply any positive or negative results?

Comment: It almost certainly means that they are still navigating the university's recruitment process, so they still need several weeks to provide an update.

Answer (score 9):

The email does not imply anything.

The hiring committee/chair really can't say much to applicants during the process other than "we are still working on it." I emailed a few while I was going through the process and they all sent back generic responses.

However, if you email them to let them know you have other offers, that is when you would expect a different response. Every school that I emailed in this situation was very forward with information (e.g., "We are making a decision on March 15th and will call you that day." or even "Here is an unofficial offer. The paperwork is processing for the real thing, give it a week."). Good luck!